# No Definition for Plugin in XSockets.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xsockets.net

I am working on a RTC Project in ASP.net and using XSockets.net for signalling purpose in VS 2013. But as I install XSockets.net 4.1.0 and try to create Xsockets.Net.BootStrapper class under App_Start folder it comes up with an error that Project doesn't contain definition for Plugin.

**BootStrapper.cs:**

```
using System.Web;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket;
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(RTC.App_Start.XSockets), "Start")]
namespace RTC.App_Start
{
    public static class XSockets
    {
        private static IXSocketServerContainer container;
        public static void Start()
        {
            container = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();
            container.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of yours

```
using System.Web;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(XSockets.WebRTC.App_Start.XSocketsWebBootstrapper), "Start")]
namespace XSockets.WebRTC.App_Start
{
    public static class XSocketsWebBootstrapper
    {
        private static IXSocketServerContainer container;
        public static void Start()
        {
            container = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();
            container.Start();
        }
    }
}
```